# Retrieving URL of a file parse.com

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I'm trying to get back the url of a file I just saved. However, the `getUrl()` method found in their documentation doesn't seem to work. I get the error:

Property 'getUrl' not found on object of type 'PFFile *'

**My code:**

```
int count = 0;    
PFObject *obj = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"File"];
    for (NSString* currentString in directoryContents){

        NSString *temp2 = [temp stringByAppendingPathComponent:currentString];
        PFFile *file = [PFFile  fileWithName:currentString contentsAtPath:temp2];
        [file saveInBackground];


        count += 1;

        NSString *filen = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"file%i",count];
        NSLog(@"%@",filen);


        [obj setObject:file forKey:filen];
        NSString* url = file.getUrl();
    }

        [obj saveInBackground];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use `file.url` as [documented](https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFFile.html#//api/name/url).

Comment: @user3883353: Please accept this answer to reward Tom for helping you. Thanks.